# How to add/indicate my own emphasis to a quote that already contains emphasis?

Tags: writing-style, quotes, emphasis

Here's my original quote:

> … at this point let’s remember that *figurative* does not mean “untrue”
> or “less important.” Figurative language teaches true and important
> matters. After one has determined the true implications of figurative
> language, it should be applied with confidence.

Please note that "figurative" is already emphasized by the author.

Now I would like to emphasize a further portion of the text, so that the quote would read like so in my piece:

> … at this point let’s remember that *figurative* does not mean “untrue”
> or “less important.” *Figurative language teaches true and important
> matters*. After one has determined the true implications of figurative
> language, it should be applied with confidence.

How can I indicate that some of the emphasis was the original author's, and some was added? To say "emphasis added" is true, but kind of implies that *all* emphasis was added, and does not distinguish which was mine, and which was the author's.

Perhaps this is too nitpicky—but on the other hand perhaps there is an answer!

Comment: I'd guess you could bold part of it and say "italics in the original, bolding added", but it would be better to find another way indicating what is important, like only quoting a smaller part, not quoting the bit with italics, or saying afterwards "particularly interesting is this bit..." (This is just personal opinion though, and you could also check whatever style guide you are writing to.)

Comment: You put this after the sentence: (bolding mine) The only way to do it is to used bold.

Comment: Combining ideas:  "...figurative does not mean 'untrue' or 'less important.'" Here, the author spells out "Figurative language teaches true and important matters. After one has determined..." And now that the line is a vanilla mirror, why does it need emphasis, let alone quoting?

Comment: I would add an emphatic phrase: "... at this point let’s remember that *figurative* does not mean “untrue” or “less important.” -> It must be understood that figurative language teaches true and important matters.  -- An alternative is to underline, but I find too much formatting to be distracting and not particularly attractive to read.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you could use different forms of emphasis, such as italics and bold. Another option that I have seen is to include a note such as: "First italicized text emphasized in original, subsequent italicized text emphasized by me."

Comment: Thank you everyone, most helpful.